# VirtualizingStackPanel stops working when overriding the default control template for ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, scrollviewer, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a listbox with a lot of items which are expensive to render. However the VirtualizingStackPanel takes care of that by only rendering the visible items. I want to override the control template for ScrollViewer since the default one has grey rectangle between the horizontal and vertical scrollbar. I just copied the one provided by Microsoft ([ScrollViewer ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) which do not have the grey rectangle issue.

This controltemplate however disables virtualization by giving the VirtualizingStackPanel endless height. That means that the VirtualizingStackPanel will render all items, since it thinks all items are visible.

In the below demo code I show 10000 items in a listbox. I verify the issue by comparing running it with the ScrollViewer style and without it. With it the demo runs very slow, resizing takes many seconds. Without the style it's very fast. I output some info about the VirtualizingStackPanel to prove my point:

Without the ScrollViewer style (Comment out the style in the XAML):

> ViewportHeight: 8
>   ExtentHeight: 10000
>   ActualHeight: 245
>   IsVirtualizing: True
>   VirtualizationMode: Standard

With the ScrollViewer style:

> ViewportHeight: 0
>   ExtentHeight: 0
>   ActualHeight: 272766.666666707
>   IsVirtualizing: True
>   VirtualizationMode: Standard

Any idea how to write a control template for a ScrollViewer that doesn't mess with virtualization?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="VirtualTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <ScrollBar 
                                Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" 
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" 
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" 
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                            <ScrollBar 
                                Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" 
                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" 
                                Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" 
                                ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" 
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}"
            ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ListBox_ScrollChanged"
            Background="Orange">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Width="400"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace VirtualTest
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public IEnumerable<double> Numbers
        {
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListBox_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
            VirtualizingStackPanel virtualizingStackPanel = FindVirtualizingStackPanel(listBox);                             
            Debug.WriteLine("ViewportHeight: " + virtualizingStackPanel.ViewportHeight);
            Debug.WriteLine("ExtentHeight: " + virtualizingStackPanel.ExtentHeight);
            Debug.WriteLine("ActualHeight: " + virtualizingStackPanel.ActualHeight);
            Debug.WriteLine("IsVirtualizing: " + VirtualizingStackPanel.GetIsVirtualizing(virtualizingStackPanel));
            Debug.WriteLine("VirtualizationMode: " + VirtualizingStackPanel.GetVirtualizationMode(virtualizingStackPanel));
        }

        private VirtualizingStackPanel FindVirtualizingStackPanel(Visual visual)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
            {
                Visual child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i) as Visual;

                if (child != null)
                {
                    if (child is VirtualizingStackPanel)
                    {
                        return child as VirtualizingStackPanel;
                    }

                    VirtualizingStackPanel found = FindVirtualizingStackPanel(child);
                    if (found != null)
                    {
                        return found;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ScrollViewer Style is copied from Blend 4 and it looks good in the output window

> ViewportHeight: 10
>   ExtentHeight: 10000
>   ActualHeight: 308
>   IsVirtualizing: True
>   VirtualizationMode: Standard

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}"/>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, that style has virtualization working. They actually set the rectangle fill brush to SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, why not just make it transparent? What was missing in my style was in the ScrollContentPresenter definition: CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}". If I add that virtualization starts working again for me. Thanks.